# How to run react and express concurently?

Tags: reactjs, express

I am building an app that has frontend-React and backend express. I am trying to concurrently run both. I edited the pakage.json file in the back end. I have two folders in my main folder frontend and backend folders. When I tried to run this it gives an error. How do I fix this error? Thanks.

```
    {
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "cd frontend && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "Ezana",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}




   [0] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
[0]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1277:14)
[0]     at listenInCluster (net.js:1325:12)
[0]     at Server.listen (net.js:1412:7)
[0]     at Function.listen (/Users/ezanatesfaye/Desktop/Canvas/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ezanatesfaye/Desktop/Canvas/backend/index.js:25:5)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
[0]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
[0] Emitted 'error' event at:
[0]     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1304:8)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[0]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
[0]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
[0]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: Which ports are you running your servers on ?

Comment: 5000 for express and 3000 for react

Comment: The error looks like to me that you already have an instance of your express server running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the app that you are running in port `5000` or change the port of you node app. You can user the following configuration as well.

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "start-dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix ../client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-dev\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Comment: ** i am getting this error now** . `[1] npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 client: npm start --prefix ../client`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 client script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`

Comment: is the client folder is inside the server folder?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you already have a process bound to the port 5000. I think you already ran the same thing before & likely that process is still assigned the same port. Try and kill process *OR* listen your server on different port. As of add this to your server side code:-

```
const A_PORT = 6000;
app.listen(A_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${A_PORT}`));
```

and always remember to terminate the process correctly by `CTRL + C`, by sending the request `SIGINT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `npm-run-all --parallel start-dev client`

Please first install `npm-run-all: "^4.1.3"` before executing above script.

Or you can try `npm run start-dev && npm run client`